# Choosing highlighting color of Visual Studio custom language with TextMate grammar

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I currently adding my own custom language to Visual Studio, based of the [TextMate grammar template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TextmateGrammarTemplate&ssr=false#overview)

I wrote a `mylanguage.json` file that works fine. However, I find it hard to know which syntax highlighting will be applied to each of my keywords.

1. How can how know which `name` key correspond to which value in "Visual Studio > option > Environnement > Fonts and Colors"? For example, what's the GUI name of `entity.other.attribute-name`?
2. How can I add custom highlighting? I would like to be able to do, in the mylanguage.json:

```json
"mykeywords": {
  "match": "(never|gonna|give|you|up)",
  "name": "keyword.other.mylanguage.specialkeyword"
},
```

And setup somewhere the this name correspond to bold, redbackground, underlined, blinking text. I suspect the empty "Themes" folder of the template is here for that, but I didn't find any documentation.